# How to use CSS position correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 `DIV`s like this

```
<div class="green">
  <div class="red">
    <div>......</div>
    <div class="yellow">......</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this structure, I want to have an output similar to this:

[image]

Green `DIV` have set to its width 100% and red `DIV` have a fixed width and set to center of the page. So my problem is I want to get my yellow `DIV` to red `DIV` having align to right of the red `DIV`.

```
.red {
   position: relative;
}

.yellow {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 20px;
}
```

But it’s not my desired output.

Answer (score 3):

here is a  fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/P77RB/ you can play with the width and height to accommodate your needs.

```
<div class="green">
<div class="red">
    <div class="yellow">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.green{
width:500px;
height:300px;
background:green;
display:table;
 }
 .red{
width:80%;
height:270px;
margin:30px auto 0px auto;
background:red;
position:relative;
}
.yellow{
position:absolute;
background:yellow;
width:200px;
height:100px;
right:0;
top:50%;
margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Comment: what happen if there is another div in red having align to left?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to have another red div inside the green div also, I put the example based on the picture?

Comment: In that case, you need to add css for that div as well. 
.red div.white {
  float: left;
  background: white
  
}

Comment: But this is not working with my actual code. Here I am using bootstrap. Green div = bootstrap .container-fluid and Red div = bootstrap .container . Yellow is a my custom div.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
.yellow {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `right: 0;`

```
.yellow {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/keyogaso/1/edit)

Adjust the height and width as per your page.

[image]

```
    .red {
   position: relative;
   width: 60%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;

}

.yellow {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   background: yellow;
   top: 20;
   height: 80%;
   width: 60%;
}


.green {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the yellow div into the red div in HTML and then set it to float: right;